# Command 'nodeos' not found

Tags: nodeos, eosio.cdt

Till yesterday **nodeos** on my machine was working fine, today I installed **eosjs** after that **eosio** commands giving errors. Just like nodeos command giving following error:

```
Command 'nodeos' not found, did you mean:

  command 'nodefs' from deb noweb
  command 'nodejs' from deb nodejs
```

The tried solutions given for the same question but not working. Same is happening for cleos or any other commands of **eosio**. 
I follow these commands again but no change in errors.

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/eosio/eosio.cdt --branch v1.4.1 --single-branch
cd eosio.cdt
./build.sh
sudo ./install.sh
```

Comment: Have look at this https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4883

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link. I have gone through this link before. But didn't find any specific solution.

Comment: Go on eosio/build/programs/nodeos and then run ./nodeos in cmd try it

Comment: I am not getting this path eosio/build/programs/nodeos. Rather I tried cd ~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config

Comment: eosio OR eos is your main eos directory which you have cloned from git.

Comment: Sorry but I have cloned directly eosio.cdt in which I didn't find this folder.

Comment: I don't think eosio.cdt provides you nodeos and cleos tool. you need this https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/ for nodeos and cleos tools.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90111/discussion-between-mr-y-and-varsha-khandre).